# Open and List files/folders in a zip archive in PHP

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

Well,

What I need is:

PHP script which can open and the echo out all top level files and folder included in a zip archive saved at location:

```
/submittions/projects/zip/file_name.zip
```

So, if a zip archive contains 3 folders and 2 files at top level where all of these three top level folders have sub folder in them as well, I should get result as:

```
folder_name_1
folder_name_2
folder_name_3
file_name_1
file_name_2
```

I tried searching here but still with nothing.

There is a tutorial for extracting but it doesn't tell clearly about listing each file:

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-open-zip-files-with-php/

I tried zip_open($path_to_zip)

While using this function, I am getting output as 5. I believe it is an error number.
All those ZIP files are set to CHMOD 777

One more thing, on applying zip_open(), if I test if file is open or not, I am getting two different cases like this:

```
$zip  =  zip_open($path);

// CHECK ONE
if($zip) {
 echo "Opened";
} else {
 echo "Failed";
}

// CHECK TWO
if(is_resource($zip)) {
 echo "Opened";
} else {
 echo "Failed";
}
```

Check ONE returns Opened, check TWO returns Failed.

I just want the file and folder names in a zip archive and it would be great if you get me a simple and straightforward solution without any part of extraction and all, if its possible?

My server's PHP configuration is here: http://academicadda.com/info.php

Below is simple code where zip.zip is in same directory:

```
<?php 
$zip    =   zip_open('zip.zip');
if(is_resource($zip)) {
echo "open";
} else {
echo "failed";
}

?>
```

OUTPUT: open

What should be code to read each top level file and folder? zip_read() ?

Comment: As `is_source()` isn't a standard PHP function, perhaps you ought to show us the code so that we can see what it's supposed to do and why it's returning `false`

Comment: Sorry, that is is_resource(). I mistyped. My bad!

Comment: I just started this from scratch. I have a directory where a zip file ab.zip resides.

I want to read top level files and folder in that archive. 
For that, as far I knw, I tried using zip_open() and then zip_read() functions... But there seems to be problem with opening zip file.

All tutorials and questions I found here and on other sites are about extracting zip archive.

Answer (score 0):

`if($zip)`returns true because its a positive value, in your case 5. And an error code 5 references to an "can't read" problem. I suggest you to check your path and permissions.

Comment: Hey, thanks, its open now. How can i read each top level file from it? or think i need some more time googling.

Comment: Try something like that: while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) { ...}. A more detailed example can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.zip-open.php#85585

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for addressing me.

It was path and permission problem.

Here is the solution I have finally got after a workaround:

```
<?php 
$zip    =   zip_open('zip.zip');

if(is_resource($zip)) {

   while (($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)))
        {
            echo $path = zip_entry_name($zip_entry);
        }

} else {
   echo "failed";
}

?>
```